# Does HDFS provide asynchronous writes?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

From going through the API and the documentation, I get the impression that hdfs does not provide completely asynchronous write operations. It has to wait for minimum replication (by default 1) of the block to be completed before the write operation returns. Is there any way to write completely asynchronously using HDFS API?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, HDFS API does not have any function to provide for asynchronous writes, as it is supposed to provide persistence and blocking write. One good idea is to accumulate the data if possible to a minimum chunk size before writing to HDFS, if performance is the goal. However, if the machine fails and you haven't written data to HDFS the data will be lost.